# Arduino IDE / Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library

Tags: esp8266

I trying to add library here but it doesn't seem to work https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

This happens
"Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library"

This problem make me no longer upload any library. any solution about this??
Manual installation does not either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install that repository as a Arduino library.

**Read the [README file](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/README.md) in that repo**. It explains how to install it using the Arduino IDE Board manager. That's the correct way to install it.